# Losing a bit when converting in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ip, bit-manipulation, bit

So let's say I have a `var testIP = '93.174.93.145';`

And I'm performing following methods:

```
function ipToBin(ip) {
    var block = ip.split('.');
    var res = 0;

    res += block[0] << 24;
    res += block[1] << 16;
    res += block[2] << 8;
    res += block[3] << 0;

    bin = res.toString(2);
    console.log('\n to bin: ', bin);
    console.log(bin.length);
    return bin;
}

function binToIP(bin) {
    var block1 = (bin.split(0, 8));
    block1 = parseInt(block1, 2);
    block1 = (block1 >> 0) & 255;

    var block2 = bin.split(9, 8);
    block2 = parseInt(block2, 2);
    block2 = (block2 >> 8) & 255;

    var block3 = bin.split(17, 8);
    block3 = parseInt(block3, 2);
    block3 = (block3 >> 16) & 255;

    var block4 = bin.split(25, 8);
    block4 = parseInt(block4, 2);
    block4 = (block4 >> 24) & 255;

    console.log((block4 + '.' + block3 + '.' + block2 + '.' + block1).toString());
}
```

Now the thing is that the binary string's length is only 31 and when converted back to IP, it returns `93.174.93.1`. Is this similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663188/why-does-tostring-cause-my-string-to-lose-a-decimal-place)? Or where exactly lies the problem I'm facing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary problem is that `toString(2)` will only output as many digits as it needs, and it only needs 31. So when you're doing your string manipulation in `binToIP`, which relies on 32 digits, you're ending up with the wrong value.

I wouldn't do string manipulation in `binToIP` at all, I'd just do the converse of what you do in `iptoBin`: Parse it to a number, then do bit manipulation to get the individual bits, then form them into a string:

```
function binToIP(bin) {
  var value = parseInt(bin, 2);
  var block1 = (value & 0xFF000000) >> 24;
  var block2 = (value & 0x00FF0000) >> 16;
  var block3 = (value & 0x0000FF00) >> 8;
  var block4 = value & 0x000000FF;
  var ip = block1 + "." + block2 + "." + block3 + "." + block4;

  return ip;
}
```

Live example:

```js
var testIP = '93.174.93.145';
snippet.log("Original IP: " + testIP);
var bin = ipToBin(testIP);
snippet.log("bin: " + bin);
var rebuiltIP = binToIP(bin);
snippet.log("Rebuilt IP : " + rebuiltIP);

function ipToBin(ip) {
  var block = ip.split('.');
  var res = 0;

  res += block[0] << 24;
  res += block[1] << 16;
  res += block[2] << 8;
  res += block[3] << 0;

  bin = res.toString(2);
  return bin;
}

function binToIP(bin) {
  var value = parseInt(bin, 2);
  var block1 = (value & 0xFF000000) >> 24;
  var block2 = (value & 0x00FF0000) >> 16;
  var block3 = (value & 0x0000FF00) >> 8;
  var block4 = value & 0x000000FF;
  var ip = block1 + "." + block2 + "." + block3 + "." + block4;

  return ip;
}
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```